# MariaDb throwing duplicate primary key error when inserting null id

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I have a table with an auto increment primary key, and an insert setting the id as null so as the use the auto increment. This is what I normally do and is the expected behaviour and works fine.

With one table I'm finding that *sometimes* (not always) Mariadb errors that the primary key is duplicated. Even though I haven't set one. But if I run the exact same query again, it works ok.

Relevant part of the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `Account` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`customer_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2558023 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And the insert:

```
INSERT INTO Account SET
id = NULL, created = '2021-09-27 14:57:28', customer_id = 2558019
```

Threw the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2558021' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

So it seems it tried to use id 2558021 as the PK when I specified null (as it should) but then found it to be a duplicate (which it shouldn't). I can see that pk 2558021 was inserted a minute later for another customer.

I did find that the auto increment set on the table definition was lower than the highest id. I don't think that should matter but I fixed it. But the issue continued.

I'm using mariadb 10.1.35 with php 7.2. I'm not using a transaction.

I can't even figure out how this happens. Is there some bug? Is there a weird set of circumstances which can cause this?

Comment: I've never seen the table AUTO_INCREMENT option be less than the highest id. I don't think that's possible in InnoDB. Either data is changing rapidly while you're checking it, or else you're looking at the wrong table or wrong schema.

Comment: Or you have a trigger defined on your account table, which inserts / updates data in another table causing the error message to appear. Since the error message does not contain any reference as to which table  caused it, you think it was caused by the accounts table.

Comment: @BillKarwin you're probably right about the auto increment. As soon as you insert using the auto increment it'll update the table def.

Comment: @Shadow Good idea on the triggers. I did check but no triggers there.

Answer (score 0):

This was a weird one and I still don't know what caused it, but I backed up the table, dropped it and reloaded from the backup and the situation seems to have resolved. Maybe there was some weird table corruption or something?